# WPF Application from Visual Studio 2010 crashes Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, freeze, visual-studio-2010, wpf

I am using visual studio 2010 on Windows 7 64bit.

I compiled and ran a simple application basically a thing a child could make. Well the second it started to run, it froze my computer and rendered it unresponsive. It continues to do this every time and for every application.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried putting in break points into your code?  Can you rule out that your program isn't eating up all the memory?

Comment: I basically stuck a button on a form and ran it. I really don't think I am eating memory. It still crashes as a blank form, so it is not my code, since I didn't add any code. 
My computer has 4 cores, windows 7, a very beastin' graphics card, and every driver and software item is up to date.

Thanks though sunpech.

Comment: Assuming (and hoping) that you have a second computer around: 

1. Can you still ping your frozen PC? If so, then most likely the graphics system is what froze, and you should (as above) update your video drivers. For that matter, if you can still ping it and it's not too dead, try using psexec.exe to reboot it remotely, so you don't have to power-cycle it. 

2. Try the same app as a Windows Forms app, verify that it doesn't hang/crash your system. 

3. Try any other WPF app you can think of, aside from VS 2010 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I tried all of your suggestions, but I have solved it.

COMODO Antivirus/Firewall blocks all applications from calling DLL's, you have to click "Allow" on the dialog that normally pops-up. But since its a DirectX DLL for WPF (since WPF uses DirectX) it froze windows along with my app.

Answer (score 1):

To freeze your entire system seems a hardware problem, or a driver problem.

Try updating your DirectX drivers. WPF uses DirectX to renter the GUI. After that, open again your app and check if it freezes.

Also, you can try to check windows event logger to see if there`s anything unusual.